# Databricks Azure database warehouse saving tables

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse

I am using the following code to write a Azure warehouse table

```html
df_execution_config_remain.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("user", user) 
  .option("password", pswd)
  .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://"+sqlserver +":"+port+";database="+database)
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", execution_config)
  .option("tempDir", dwtmp)
  .mode("Overwrite")
  .save()
```

But Overwrite will drop the table and recreate .

Question
1. I found the new create table is having round robin distribution. which I don't want

2. the column is having different length with the original table, varchar(256)
3. I don't want to use append, because I would like to clear the rows in the current table

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Refer to the tableOptions parameter under the following link:
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html#parameters

Q2:Are you being affected by the maxStrLength parameter under that same link?

Q3: I think your approach is sound, but an alternative might be to use the preActions parameter under that same link, and TRUNCATE the table before loading.